# Как прослушать вебсокет в puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

При переходе на нужный мне сайт, на нем открывается вебсокет (один), где постоянно происходит обмен данных. Ссылка на вебсокет неизвестна. Мне нужно найти данный вебсокет и прослушивать какие данные приходят и отсылаются с помощью puppeteer.

Нашел в интернете такой код:

```
const client = page._client;

client.on('Network.webSocketFrameSent', ({requestId, timestamp, response}) => {
    try {
        console.log(response)
    }
})
```

Однако он работает только на старом puppeteer. Я использую puppeteer-extra 3.3.4
При выпоплнении кода выводит ошибку:

```
TypeError: client.on is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, _client на новой версии puppeteer работает как функция

Было:

```
await page._client
```

Стало:

```
await page._client()
```